# What happens to legacy contracts given breaking changes to cargo-contract v3?

Tags: ink, smart-contract, substrate-contracts-node, substrate-node, cargo-contract

In the [cargo contract v3](https://github.com/paritytech/cargo-contract/releases/tag/v3.0.0) release, breaking changes were made for how contracts are built (`cdylib` -> `bin`) and specifying `no_main`.

I've found that cargo contract v2 produces contracts compatible with `substrate-contracts-node` version 0.24 and below but incompatible with version 0.25 and above.

Conversely I've found that cargo contract v3 produces contracts that are not compatible with `substrate-contracts-node` version 0.24 and below but compatible with v0.25 upwards.

So my question is this: how do chains deal with this breaking change? If my chain is currently running version 0.24 of `substrate-contracts-node` and all contracts are built using cargo contract version 2, the new contracts from `cargo-contract` v3 are incompatible and are rejected on code upload (we're experiencing this with rococo contracts node at the moment!).

I assume the chain has to upgrade, but what happens to the existing contracts which are in the old format (`cargo-contract` v2 format)? Do they get purged? Do they run in some legacy mode? are they rebuilt in the correct (v3) format?

Context: I don't run my own chain, I build smart contracts and am curious :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Contracts are upgraded between releases of the contracts pallet, see [here](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/blob/master/substrate/frame/contracts/src/migration/v15.rs)